# Group values from a few rows into an array

Tags: presto

I'm using presto, and I have a dataset of rows with ids and values, each id can have multiple rows with multiple values.

I need to group the values into an array and create one row of "value"s for each "id" (a comma delimited string of all values per id).

The number of values for each id can be different (some will have 1, some will have ~10)
Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I am not sure i understand the requirements (you can add some examples), but generally you may find [`array_agg`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#array_agg) and [`format`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#format) functions useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go through [array_agg](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html"Aggregate Functions")

```
select 
    id, array_agg(value) 
from 
    database
group by 
    id
```

I hope this is what you want.